# C# conection string to MS access file on MS Teams

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbconnection

The app that I developed connects with this database

```
connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                   @"Data source= " + databasePath + "Password=pass1234;";
```

It is working properly.

I would like to know if is possible to put the database file on Microsoft teams.
How will be the connection string?

Comment: hi your query has unclear in my case ; so what your're looking for ? you're trying to add some file to Ms Teams using C# ? It's case you have to take look at Ms Graph Api and find the way to sending some file to directory (Teams Team Canal was Sharepoint Online directory )

Comment: Microsoft Teams files are stored on SharePoint. Could you please check this docs? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/publish-a-database-to-a-sharepoint-site-8287ed04-9c65-46c4-bbdb-c965c56b018c